# Disabling a Material UI button when there is no value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am writing a create form and want to conditionally disable the submit button when the input value are null or and empty string.  I wrote an if statement to set disabled to 'true' when the conditional are true and false then they aren't, but the problem is, then the form initially loads, there seems to be no condition. Let me explain, I have a console.log for values, but then the form loads I ma simply getting empty curly brackets '{}'.  So when I wrote my conditional as such:

```
const disabled = () => {
 if (values.name === null) { return true;}
 if (values.name === '') { return true;}
 else { return false; }
}
```

the empty curly brackets worked to fulfill the else statement and were setting disabled to false.

I have tried a few other things but keep either not being able to disable the button, or causing an infinite re-render loop.  How can disable this button when those conditions are true?  can I force the values to be empty strings and initially have empty curly brackets instead of values?

here is what I have going right now:

**my form**

```
export function CreateForm(props) {
    const { closeModal, refreshTable, ltCreateUrl } = props;

    const initialValues = {
      name: '',
    };  
  

    const validate = (fieldValues = values) => {
        const temp = { ...errors };
        if ('name' in fieldValues)
            { temp.name = fieldValues.name ? '' : 'Department Name is required.'; }
        if ('description' in fieldValues)
            { temp.description = fieldValues.description ? '' : 'Description is required.'; }
        setErrors({
            ...temp
        });
        if (fieldValues === values)
            { return Object.values(temp).every(x => x === ''); }
    };


// Disable Submit button if values are null or blank
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(true);

    const handleSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (validate()){
        createRecord(values);
        closeModal();
      }
    };

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
          <Grid container spacing={0}>
           <Controls.Input
               type='text'
               onChange={handleInputChange}
               label='Department Name'
               name='name'
               value={values.name !== null ? values.name : ''}
               error={errors.name}
             />
          </Grid>
          <Grid>
              <Controls.Button
                  type='submit'
                  text='Submit'
                  onClick={handleSubmit}
                  disabled={disabled}
              />
              <Controls.Button
                  text='Reset'
                  onClick={resetForm}
              />
              <Controls.Button
                  text='Cancel'
                  onClick={closeModal}
              />
          </Grid>
      </Form>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a disabled hook if your input value is reactive. Try this;

```
         <Controls.Button
              type='submit'
              text='Submit'
              onClick={handleSubmit}
              disabled={!values.name}
          />
```

Comment: both solutions were great but this one was super simple.  I also had a description field in my form as well, so wrote it as disabled={!values.name || !values.description} and it worked like a charm.